# I used pifont but the header in some pages shows strange symbols

Tags: header-footer, pifont

I used pifont package because I would like to use the checkmark and cross. I also used a package to set my header (both left and right). But the header of some pages is very strange. It seems that the two packages are not compatible.

Here is my input:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\uppercase{Lee}}
\fancyfoot{}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{apalike}
```

Here is the correct header (screenshot):

[image]

The head of some pages is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please provide complete small document which reproduce your problem. So far you show only document preamble ...

Comment: I'm sure it's not the cause of the problem, but you're loading `fancyhdr` twice.  Once is sufficient.